# Wordpress - Blog redirection 301

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

At the beginning my blog was accessible from example.com and i have move all files to "blog" folder and create blog.example.com redirection from ovh.

Works fine but old links from google give me a 404 so i tried to make some redirection 301 like:

```
Redirect 301 /my-post http://blog.example.com/my-post
```

but that give me a inifinite loop.

Comment: Maybe this will help https://wordpress.org/support/topic/domain-settings-and-htaccess-resulting-in-infinite-loop-redirect

Comment: I am not sure to understand, redirection 301 not be necessary in this case ?

Comment: Thats my understanding,my WP knowledge is wobbly at best.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, I don't understand.

Comment: Is your htaccess file in the root folder?

Comment: No it's in /www/blog with all WP files, in root folder i have my other files.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps but try absolute paths like:

```
Redirect 301 http://example.com/blog/my-post http://blog.example.com/my-post
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /blog/my-post http://blog.example.com/my-post
```

Because the code     `Redirect 301 /my-post http://blog.example.com/my-post`
 will actually redirect /my-post requests regardless if it is

```
http://blog.example.com/my-post
```

or

```
http://example.com/blog/my-post
```